# Is it necessary to put nuances indication at the start and end of a crescendo/decrescendo?

Tags: sheet-music, dynamics

On one song I'm writing, I'd like to finish the song with a *decrescendo* on two measures. 
[image]

My question is, is it better (or at least useful) to add a nuance at the end of the *decrescendo* like in the following image ?

[image]

Thank you for your time and your help !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want it to end very quietly then, yes a ***ppp*** marking is appropriate. Although it is common to decrescendo to a very low volume at the end of a piece, it is still best to make your intention absolutely clear.

However, you could also use the markings ***al niente*** (*lit. to nothing*) or ***morendo*** (*lit. dying*) to indicate that you want the volume to “die away” to nothing (or almost nothing). You can also use a specific kind of decrescendo hairpin that has a “o” attached to the pointy end to indicate that the music decrescendos to silence:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In general I would recommend a closing closing indication, since

- you make your intention clear to player or conductor and whats obvious to you may not be for them
- hairpins are not the only way, for a textual *decresc.* it is even more important
- if the final bar is well-populated (and I'm not exactly a friend of the percent-like repetition sign) and the decrescendo is **not** supposed to stretch to the last note, it is far easier to give an exact place.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the player has to know how far down the *decresc.* (whether notated as a hairpin or not) goes.  Not all decrescendi are *al niente*.

To extend the topic to crecendi as well as diminuendi, there is a great difference between these two examples.

[image]

Some would suggest the first would be ok without the central dynamic.  Others (me included) would say that it merely indicated normal expressive playing - is you DIDN'T want a natural *cresc.* and *decresc.* *senza cresc.* might be needed!   We see a lot more of this (over-)notation than we used to, presumably the result of trying to make notation software play back 'expressively'.